# Prove that the tetragon ABCD also has an inscribed circle

Tags: geometry, algebraic-geometry

There is given convex tetragon ABCD and some points J,K,L,M on the line segments AB,BC,CD,DA respectively. The intersection of  JL and KM is T.  Each of the tetragons AJTM,BKTJ,CLTK, and DMTL have an inscribed circle.

Prove that the tetragon ABCD also has an inscribed circle.

Answer (score 0):

there is a similar [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/320847/tangential-quadrilateral/327108#327108) with a geometry Theorem。 you may proof this geometry theorem first if you haven't see it before. then use it to proof your question.